# extract date from file name use shell script

Tags: linux, extract

I have file names like these

```
File Name_9.30.11.csv
File Name_11.30.13.csv
```

I want to extract the dates and put into `201109` and `201311`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex match on the filenames and extract the dates. Based on the format of your example file name, a sample code to turn into the format you specified:

```
#!/bin/bash

fn='File Name_9.30.11.csv';
regex='([0-9]{1,2})\.([0-9]{1,2})\.([0-9]{1,2})';
if [[ $fn =~ $regex ]]; then
    mn="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}";
    day="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}";
    yr="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}";
    dt=`date -d"$mn/$day/$yr" +%Y%m`
    echo "date is: $dt";
fi
```